# PostgreSQL multi-column WHERE = ANY(ARRAY)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with three columns, "id", "letter" and "number". I have a list of pairs of "letter" and "number", for which I need to get the "id"s in single query. Obviously, the easy solution is to use n queries, where n is the size of the list.

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE number=... AND letter=...
```

But that requires n queries, in my case it is millions and there is large overhead. Previously, I only had a filter on list of "number"s, so I used

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE number = ANY(ARRAY[...])
```

Is there some syntax that would do what I need, something like

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE PAIR[letter,number] = ANY(ARRAY[PAIR[...],...])
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you can certainly use an ARRAY with the [`<@` (is-contained-by)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) operator or the [`ANY` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.28.16), you don't need arrays for that.  A `JOIN` on fixed values will most certainly run much faster than the other options.

Consider the following `test` table with data:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
    test(id SERIAL, letter TEXT, num NUMERIC);

WITH letters AS (
    SELECT chr(generate_series(65, 90)) AS letter
)
,numbers AS (
    SELECT generate_series(101, 999) AS num 
)
INSERT INTO test(letter, num)
SELECT  letter, num 
FROM    letters, numbers
```

You can now add your values to a query and do a `JOIN`.  For example, the following query finds the `id` of the pairs ('A', 105), ('B', 110), and ('C', 879):

```
SELECT  id
FROM    test T
    JOIN (VALUES    /* your query criteria goes here */
        ('A', 105)
       ,('B', 110)
       ,('C', 879)
    ) AS V(l, n) 
        ON T.letter = V.l AND T.num = V.n
```

Which returns (assuming no prior writes were made to the test table):

```
id  |
----|
   5|
 909|
2577|
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I have finally discovered `SELECT id FROM table WHERE (number, letter) = ANY (VALUES(1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'C'))` which seems the shortest.

Answer (score 5):

You could use an array of rows:

```
select id from table where (letter, number) = any(array[(l1, n1), (l2, n2), ...])
```

if you're set on using `= any`. You might need to include a lot of type casting to make sure everything lines up so it could be uglier than joining to a VALUES list.

Comment: This does not work, however, the issue might be that the second row is actually "character varying". I'm getting **ERROR:  cannot compare dissimilar column types character varying and unknown at record column 2**

Comment: Hence the "You might need to include a lot of type casting to make sure everything lines up" note at the end. You might need to say things like `(l1::varchar, n1::int)` to get the types right.