# pandas read_sql_query with params matching multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql

I'm trying to query a table using `pandas.read_sql_query`, where I want to match multiple columns to python lists passed in as `param` arguments. Running into various `psycopg2` errors when trying to accomplish this.

Ideally, I would provide a reproducible example, but unfortunately, that's not possible here due to the SQL connection requirement. If there is some way to provide a reproducible example, please let me know and I will edit the code below. Assume that the entries of `col1` are strings and those of `col2` are numeric values.

Note that I'm trying to ensure that each row of `col1` and `col2` matches the corresponding combination of `list1` and `list2`, so it would not be possible to do separate `where` clauses for each, i.e., `where col1 = any(%(list1)s) and col2 = any(%(list2)s)`.

First, I tried passing the lists as separate parameters and then combining them into an array within the SQL query:

```
import pandas as pd
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = [1,2,3]

pd.read_sql_query(
    """
    select * from table
    where (col1, col2) = any(array[(%(list1)s, %(list2)s)])
    """,
    con = conn,
    params = {'list1': list1, 'list2':list2}

)
```

When I try this, I get `Datatype Mismatch: cannot compare dissimilar columns of type text and text[] at column 1`.

Also tried the following variant, where I passed a list of lists into `param`:

```
pd.read_sql_query(
    """
    select * from table
    where (col1, col2) = any(%(arr)s)
    """,
    con = conn,
    params = {'arr': [[x,y] for x,y in zip(list1,list2)]}

)
```

Here, I got `DataError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation) in valid input syntax for integer: "a"`.

Tried a few other minor variants of the above, but every attempt threw some kind of error. So, what's the syntax needed in order to accomplish this?

**EDIT:**
Including a reproducible example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

list1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
list2 = [1, 2, 3]
n = 100

engine = create_engine(
    "postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:password@localhost:5432/database"
)

np.random.seed(2022)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": np.random.choice(list1, n, replace=True),
        "col2": np.random.choice(list2, n, replace=True),
    }
)

# write table to database
df.to_sql("toy_table", engine, if_exists="replace", index=False)

# query with where any
df_query = pd.read_sql_query(
    """
    select * from toy_table
    where col1 = any(%(list1)s) and col2=any(%(list2)s)
    """,
    con=engine,
    params={"list1": list1, "list2": list2},
)

# expected output
rows = [(x, y) for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]
df_expected = df.loc[df.apply(lambda x: tuple(x.values) in rows, axis=1)]

# Throws assertion error
assert df_expected.equals(df_query)
```

Comment: [Do the answers to this question help?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55029201/9044370)

Comment: @Paddy Alton - tried that initially, but I need additional help on the syntax since we're passing python lists as params in this case (and not just a few values within the query itself).

Comment: Right, but your bound parameters ultimately have to evaluate to the same syntax. Can you get a query to work if you write it out in full with your example values? If so, you can then start trying to inject some appropriately formatted parameterised values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution that works for any number of input lists:

```
df_query = pd.read_sql_query(
    """
    select * from toy_table
    join (select unnest(%(list1)s) as list1, unnest(%(list2)s) as list2) as tmp
    on col1 = list1 and col2 = list2
    """,
    con=engine,
    params={"list1": list1, "list2": list2},
)

# expected output
rows = [(x, y) for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]
df_expected = df.loc[df.apply(lambda x: tuple(x.values) in rows, axis=1)]

assert df_query.equals(df_expected)
```

Answer (score 1):

To make a comparison of exact pairs you could convert your array to a dictionary then to JSON, taking advantage of PostgreSQL JSON functions and operators, like this:

```
#combine lists into a dictionary then convert to json
json1 = json.dumps(dict(zip(list1, list2)))
```

then query request should be

```
df = pd.read_sql_query(
            """
            select * 
            from "table"
            where concat('{"',col1,'":',col2,'}')::jsonb <@ %s::jsonb
            """,
            con = conn,
            params = (json1,)
        )
```

Or a more general approach for n columns

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = [1,2,3]
list3 = ['z', 'y', 'x']

#assemble a json
json1 = ','.join(['"f1": "'+x+'"' for x in list1])
json2 = ','.join(['"f2": '+str(x) for x in list2])
json3 = ','.join(['"f3": "'+x+'"' for x in list3])
json_string = '{'+json1+', '+json2+ ', '+json3+'}'
```

the query

```
df = pd.read_sql_query(
            """
            select * 
            from "table"
            where row_to_json(row(col1,col2,col3))::jsonb <@ %s::jsonb
            """,
            con = conn,
            params = (json_string,)
        )
```

Tested with python 3.10.6

Comment: I tested this and it works; however, it only does so for 2 parameters. The case I provided here was just a toy example. I'm actually looking for a solution that works for any number of parameters. Also, edited the question to include a reproducible example.

Comment: Added a general solution for n columns.